# Android | The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

I have the following adapter:

```
@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
    holder.itemView.setEnabled(mAllowClicks);
    holder.itemView.setClickable(mAllowClicks);
}

@Override
public RealmViewHolder onCreateRealmViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_layout, viewGroup, false);
    myViewHolder vh = new myViewHolder(v);

    return vh;
}
```

When i run my application, i receive the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3883)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3736)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3681)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:638)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:7054)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:7012)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:7000)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1428)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1193)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1043)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:4357)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

I am using RealmRecyclerAdapter, anyone have a clue of what is going on?

Thanks!!

I'm adding items to the adapter like this:

```
mList = mRealm.where(RealmItem.class).findAll();
mAdapter.UpdateList(mList);
```

This is the UpdateList function:

```
    public void UpdateList(RealmResults<RealmItem> newList) {
    super.updateRealmResults(newList);
    mList= newList;
}
```

Comment: share the activity code where you're setting up the `RecyclerView`

Comment: In the section where you're adding childs, before adding any child use the method: parent.removeAllViews()

Comment: Can u post RealmViewHolder as well.?

Comment: Ashish, what part of the activity code you want? its a very long fragment which contains alot of things that not all of them are relevant, Luca, where should i add the parent.removeAllViews? and who is this parent attribute? Raghavendra, the realmviewholder implementation is here : https://github.com/thorbenprimke/realm-recyclerview/blob/master/library/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmViewHolder.java

Comment: add the code at where you add the child to the adapter

Comment: are you trying to add a lot of views to it ?!!

Comment: At the beggining i'm adding all the items that i fetched from the server, later on i am adding only the next page of items.

Comment: well, kindly add the code of the adding processes to the question

Comment: I have added the adding process :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happens when an item added twice to the adapter, so, when it added the second time, it detects that it is already has a parent and it can't have more than one parent, hence, the error generated.

To solve that you have to firstly create a new instance of the list(or whatever the view you adding) each time you add it to the adapter, or at least create a new variable for each view you adding.

And about the method `updateRealmResults`, as stated in the [documentation of Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/1.0.1/api/io/realm/RealmBaseAdapter.html#updateRealmResults-io.realm.RealmResults-) it is deprecated now and it has to be replaced with the method [updateDate](https://realm.io/docs/java/1.0.1/api/io/realm/RealmBaseAdapter.html#updateData-io.realm.OrderedRealmCollection-) which takes the following signature:

```
public void updateData(OrderedRealmCollection<T> data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just have ended a similar situation.

In my case, it was a RecyclerView that contains a list of complex layout components.

solved using:

```
holder.itemView.removeView(yourListHere.getRespectiveClassMethod());
```

as the last instruction inside onBindViewHolder method.